# Dynamically make tables/columns readonly/hidden in ASP.NET DD

Tags: asp.net, security, dynamic-data

I'm making a security permission system for a Dynamic Data site based on the article [Securing Dynamic Data Preview 4 Refresh](http://csharpbits.notaclue.net/2009/07/securing-dynamic-data-preview-4-refresh.html). The system contains an additional permission kind: "deny an operation for a record/field if a record is not owned by an user".

If an user can read only own objects, we need to have an always enabled filter in List and check permissions in Details. If an user can write only own objects, we need to check permissions in Edit and Delete, remove "Edit/Delete" links from some rows in List, make "User" field readonly and provide its value in Insert. I didn't think about column-level permissions of this kind yet.

So, the main problem, as I see at this moment: too many places to place the same checks (I didn't even think of malicious user crafting POST data). Also I couldn't make make a field in Insert at the same readonly and having a value which is displayed and saved to DB (I don't want to place that in the model partial classes because I think that there are already too many places that need to be edited to implement this functionality).

1. Is there a single place to deny a read or write operation with an object depending on the object value?
2. How can I provide a default value to the field, so that it will be shown on the Insert page, inserted to the DB and couldn't be changed by the user before inserting?

Answer (score 0):

The following assumes you're using LINQ to SQL.

> Is there a single place to deny a read
>   or write operation with an object
>   depending on the object value?

**Reads**

I know of no simpler way to restrict reads than to add a filter to all the relevant *LinqDataSource* controls. If you are able to implement your filter generally, you can write one [QueryCreated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.queryabledatasource.querycreated.aspx) handler, then add a single line registering your custom handler to all the page templates.

**Writes**

In the [Dynamic Data metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488539.aspx), add an *OnValidate* partial method to all the relevant tables. If the current user is not allowed to [ChangeAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.changeaction.aspx) the given record, throw an exception. You will still have to update all the page templates to hide UI elements that the user does not have access to, but at least you can rest assured that the worst that could happen in some unexpected case is that the user sees an error page.

> How can I provide a default value to
>   the field, so that it will be shown on
>   the Insert page, inserted to the DB
>   and couldn't be changed by the user
>   before inserting?

Perhaps look at some combination of adding an *OnCreated* and *OnValidate* partial methods. See also: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538234/automatically-set-a-property-value-for-a-new-record-in-a-dynamic-data-application/4895562#4895562).